# ¿Cuál es el significado de la expresión "mala copa"?

Tags: méxico, coloquialismos

¿Cuál es el significado de la expresión "mala copa"?

Ejemplo:

> Anoche en la fiesta, Juan andaba de mala copa.

Comment: Simplemente por añadir un dato a las excelentes respuestas: debe tratarse de una expresión usada en latinoamérica, pero en España yo al menos jamás había oído esa expresión...

Comment: Somewhat related http://www.todotango.com/Spanish/las_obras/Tema.aspx?id=FyxkaAeMTXo=

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From [malacopa / mala copa in Wordreference](http://forum.wordreference.com/showthread.php?t=725596):

> Se dice que una persona anda de mala copa cuando al emborracharse se pone agresivo o molesto.

Answer (score 1):

En Guadalajara, la expresión "malacopa" se refiere a una persona que suele portarse de forma agresiva, molesta, antisocial o impertinente cuando está bajo la influencia del alcohol. "Malacopear" o "andar de malacopa", a su vez, es adoptar una actitud de ese tipo o hacer actos indebidos como resultado del abuso del alcohol.

Answer (score 0):

En México la expresión **mala copa** se usa con un significado parecido a **mala onda**, es decir algo mal, indeseable.

Según yo solo se puede usar **mala copa** en referencia a como se porta una persona mientras que 'mala onda' puede referirse a una ación o algo que ha pasado.

Cuando escucho mala copa pienso en una copa de vino que se ha echado a perder, es la idea de algo pudrido, amargado, que te deja con un sabor feo en la boca. Por ejemplo el mal comportamiento de alguien que te hace arrugar la cara.